# Anki latex spacing

Tags: spacing, anki

I am using Anki with the following header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,graphicx,overpic,color,verbatim,stackrel,url,float,enumerate}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
```

My card has the following text:

```
[latex]
\begin{align*}
X_n \overset{\mathcal{L}^p}{\to} X \; \text{if} \; ||X_n - X||_p \to 0 as n \to \infty
\end{align*}
[/latex]
```

But it is being rendered as:

[image]

My question is: Why is the spacing between the `0`, `as`, and `n` so strange? I can manually fix this by adding `\;` everywhere, but is this normal? This does not happen in my normal latex documents outside of Anki (where I use `ieeetran`). Thank you

Comment: `\mbox{ as }`, not `as`

Comment: Thanks but what makes this necessary? I normally work under `ieeetran` and this is something I dont have to do there

Comment: Under all versions of TeX, the output, given the same input, would be exactly the same. Note that you are already using `\text{if}`, why should `as` behave differently?

Comment: I was using `\text{if}` because otherwise its italicized

Comment: "This does not happen in my normal latex documents outside of Anki (where I use `ieeetran`)." I don't understand this at all. All I can say is you must have been very lucky to get this far before encountering this. All I can do is urge you to use `\text{}` (if using `amsmath`) or `\mbox{}` for text in math mode, including interword spaces. In short, math mode is for maths, and everything in it is assumed to be maths. Thus, single letters are treated as variables and spaced accordingly. If you want to put words in, you have to enter a text mode, by issuing `\text{}` or `\mbox{}`

Comment: input `as n` is the same as `asn` or `a s n` and is typeset as the product of three variables, in math italic.  You need to mark up the word `an` you would have to do the same in ieeetran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct input should be

```
\begin{align*}
X_n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}^p} X \text{ if } \lVert X_n - X\rVert_p \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty
\end{align*}
```

Spaces in math mode are ignored, but not in `\text` that suspends the math mode. So `as n` is treated as the product of `a` times `s` times `n`.

Using `\overset` gives too short an arrow, `\;` doesn't provide the correct spacing.